# NSubstitute virtual getter returning substitution using ForPartsOf throws exception

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

I am trying to mock one property of an object

There is a **similar question:** [Returning the result of a method that returns another substitute throws an exception in NSubstitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643526/returning-the-result-of-a-method-that-returns-another-substitute-throws-an-excep)
But the accepted answer is not working for me.

```
void Main()
{
    var obj = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyObject>();
    //WORKS, But I need a partial mock!:
    //var obj = Substitute.For<MyObject>();

    obj.PropClass.Returns(Substitute.For<PropClass>());

    //It's suggestion, Fails, same error:
    //var returnValue = Substitute.For<PropClass>();
    //obj.PropClass.Returns(returnValue);

    //Fails, same error:
    //Lazy implementation of *similar question*
    //Func<PropClass> hello = () => Substitute.For<PropClass>();
    //obj.PropClass.Returns(x => hello());

    //Fails, same error:
    //I believe what *similar question* suggests
    //obj.PropClass.Returns(x => BuildSub());

    obj.PropClass.Dump("Value");
}

public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject()
    {
        _propClasses = new List<PropClass>();
    }
    private readonly IList<PropClass> _propClasses;
    public virtual IEnumerable<PropClass> PropClasses { get { return _propClasses; } }
    public virtual PropClass PropClass { get { return PropClasses.FirstOrDefault(); } }
}
public class PropClass
{
}

public PropClass BuildSub()
{
    return Substitute.For<PropClass>();
}
```

These fail with the exception:

```
CouldNotSetReturnDueToTypeMismatchException:
Can not return value of type PropClassProxy_9 for MyObject.get_PropClasses (expected type IEnumerable`1).

Make sure you called Returns() after calling your substitute (for example: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(value)),
and that you are not configuring other substitutes within Returns() (for example, avoid this: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub())).

If you substituted for a class rather than an interface, check that the call to your substitute was on a virtual/abstract member.
Return values cannot be configured for non-virtual/non-abstract members.

Correct use:
  mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);

Potentially problematic use:
  mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub());
Instead try:
  var returnValue = ConfigOtherSub();
  mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);
```

Comment: If you run into this issue a lot, can you please let me know? We may have to change the partial mocks API to make configuration a bit more involved but work more reliably. We have an alternate approach we can switch to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, this is a bit of a tricky one. First, the solution is to stop `obj.PropClass` from calling the base implementation:

```
obj.When(x => { var get = x.PropClass; }).DoNotCallBase();
obj.PropClass.Returns(prop);
```

Now the explanation. NSubstitute records the calls made on a substitute, and when we call `Returns`, it grabs the last call made and tries to configure that to return a specific value.

What's happening when `obj.PropClass.Returns(prop)` runs is that the real `obj.PropClass` is called, which in turn calls `obj.PropClasses`, so NSubstitute now thinks `obj.PropClasses` is the last call. The `Returns` then tries to return a single `PropClass` when `PropClasses` expects an `IEnumerable<PropClass>`, hence the exception.

The fix above stops `obj.PropClass` from calling the base implementation immediately, so the last call does not get replaced with the `PropClasses` one and `Returns` can work as expected.

Admittedly this is quite awful, and one of the reasons we held out putting partial mocks into NSubstitute for so long. NSub's nice syntax comes at the price of it not always being able to distinguish when the developer is configuring a call from when real code needs to run. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Was so close to that... definitely tried `obj.When(x => { var get = x.PropClass; }).DoNotCallBase().Returns(prop)` (which does not work)

Comment: I have tried this solution as well and similar to Thymine, i am having no luck.

Comment: For the above answer to work ensure you have the property set as overridable.

Comment: Tried doing the same with the method where methodA is consumed by methodB of a concrete object I want to proxify methodA for methodB test cases.