# Nsubstitute Returns is not overriden in an other test case?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, nunit, nsubstitute

If i have Method which i want to check, and for some reason, i want to split the test case in 2 separate cases i would love to do this :

```
    [Test]
    public void EditCustomerShouldReturnExceptionWhenCustomerIsNotCreated()
    {
        var c = new CustomerViewModel();
        _customerRepositoryMock.Update(Arg.Any<Customer>()).Returns(x => { throw new Exception(); });
        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => _customerService.EditCustomer(c));
    }

    [Test]
    public void EditCustomerShouldReturnTrueWhenCustomerIsCreated()
    {
        var c = new CustomerViewModel();
        _customerRepositoryMock.Update(Arg.Any<Customer>()).Returns(true);
         Assert.IsTrue(_customerService.EditCustomer(c));
    }
```

But the problem here is that when first test case is passed .Update return value is an exception so when second test case want to get return value it is also getting new Exception(); as return value? why does it happening? how do i override return values for the same method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your `_customerRepositoryMock` is a field in your test class which you are initializing in your `SetUp` method. I am not sure why the setup values are retained after each test passes because the `SetUp` method is supposed to run before each test method. Have you also implemented a `TearDown`?

In general though, I would strongly recommend you use local variables instead of fields. Especially in tests, and even more so when you are setting up your mocks in a different way for each test method.

You won't get this behavior if you use local variables.

**EDIT:** Try this:

```
[Test]
public void EditCustomerShouldReturnExceptionWhenCustomerIsNotCreated()
{
    var c = new CustomerViewModel();
    var customerRepositoryMock = Substitute.For<ICustomerRepository>();
    var customerService = new CustomerService(customerRepositoryMock);
    customerRepositoryMock.Update(Arg.Any<Customer>()).Returns(x => { throw new Exception(); });
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => customerService.EditCustomer(c));
}

[Test]
public void EditCustomerShouldReturnTrueWhenCustomerIsCreated()
{
    var c = new CustomerViewModel();
    var customerRepositoryMock = Substitute.For<ICustomerRepository>();
    var customerService = new CustomerService(customerRepositoryMock);
    customerRepositoryMock.Update(Arg.Any<Customer>()).Returns(true);
     Assert.IsTrue(customerService.EditCustomer(c));
}
```

Or, looking at [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643526/returning-the-result-of-a-method-that-returns-another-substitute-throws-an-excep), you might just have to change the return value of your second method into a lambda:

```
_customerRepositoryMock.Update(Arg.Any<Customer>()).Returns(x => true);
```

Which is what you would prefer, I think.